# ScopedModelDescendant String returns null. Not retrieving state

Tags: dart, flutter, state, state-management

I am refactor app to use `scoped_model` but have issue. State not seem to be pass correct between widget.

I am start with add `ScopedModel` to top of widget tree on startup.:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    UserModel().initialiseValues();

    return ScopedModel<UserModel>(
      model: UserModel(),

    child: MaterialApp(
        home: new Page(),
    ),
    );
  }
```

This call `.initialiseValues();` so the model read from `SharedPreferences` and store in variables:

```
class UserModel extends Model {

  String _name;
  String get name => _name;

void initialiseValues() async {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

_name = sharedPrefs.getString('name');
print(‘_name from sharedPrefs is $_name');
print(‘name from sharedPrefs is $name');


notifyListeners();
}
}
```

Both print statement return correct name.

But when I try call using `ScopedModelDescendant` in another page `name` return null:

```
class PageFive extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(

    builder: (context, child, model) =>

Text('${model.name}'),

    );

  }
}
```

`Text('${model.name}')`, return `null`

Anyone know why `name` return null?
I have look hard for solve but no idea why.

Comment: @pskink Yes. Thanks. I have update question. I no know why `_name` is null when called.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two problems:

1.- You are calling `.initialiseValues()` in a static way when the method is not static. And then you are creating a new diferent `UserModel` inside the `ScopedModel`.

2.- You are calling an `async` function inside the first `build()` method but you are not certain when it is going to finish and possibly, the `UserModel` is not fully initialized when building the tree.

You should maybe have a boolean variable (or check the `.name` for null) and set it to true when initialized.

In the build method, if that variable is false you could return a `CircularProgressIndicator` and when true just return your widget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  var userModel = UserModel()..initialiseValues();

  return ScopedModel<UserModel>(
    model: userModel,
    child: MaterialApp(
      home: new Page(),
    ),
  );
}

class PageFive extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return ScopedModelDescendant<UserModel>(
    builder: (context, child, model) {
       if (model.name == null)
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
       else
          return Text('${model.name}');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But I no think this is the issue. I can see from print statement that UserModel is fully initialize.

Comment: Yes, but the print statement is inside the initialise method and it is normal that it is not null there after the `await` call. Try the new code I have added.

Comment: Thanks. I have try you code but CircularProgressIndicator is on loop and no stop

Comment: I see the problem. I have edited the answer. The problem must be in the way you create your `UserModel()` and call the `initialiseValues()`

Comment: Thanks for reply! Can you explain more problem 1? What mean 'You are calling .initialiseValues() in a static way when the method is not static'?

Comment: Have you tried the code? It's not really static but you are creating an instance and immediately calling the `initialiseValues`. And later you are creating a new completely different instance. You are initialising an instance but passing as parameter another one.

Comment: Thanks! It work! I think understand now. So problem was I was not store UserModel() instance?

Comment: Yes. You were creating two instances. You initialised the first one but then passed as parameter the second one.